# Drupal Pricing Table Module

Tags: 7

What is the best way to create a Drupal pricing table for Drupal Commerce? I love [the pricing table](https://www.drupalgardens.com/pricing) mentioned in [this discussion](http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/pricing-plans-table). But I can't believe there is no ready-made module. What's your recommended architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Google-fu has failed you  :)

[Commerce price table](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table):

> Drupal Commerce contrib project that allows to have a secondary price field that considers the quantity for displaying and using the prices. It also provides a field formatter to display the price/quantity values as a table.

Comment: I've seen your suggested module but it was not enough. Pricing tables need not depend on quantity. They have multiple criterias for each option. Is it possible to configure the commerce price table module to behave like this table? https://www.drupalgardens.com/pricing